# making select tag with vue-for

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am currently developing frontend with Argon for vue.js.
Free Argon template doesn't support type select for `base-input` so I decided to make it myself.
Here is my code:

```
<template>
// ...
<base-input alternative
  type="select"
  :options="genders"
  addon-left-icon="ni ni-circle-08">
</base-input>
// ...
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app-footer',
  data() {
    return {
      genders: [
        { value: 0, text: 'Select Gender' },
        { value: 1, text: 'Male' },
        { value: 2, text: 'Female' }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

BaseInput.vue:

```
<template>
// ...
<slot v-bind="slotData">
            <select v-if="$attrs.type==='select'"
                    :value="value"
                    v-on="listeners"
                    v-bind="$attrs"
                    class="form-control"
                    :class="[{'is-valid': valid === true}, {'is-invalid': valid === false}, inputClasses]"
                    aria-describedby="addon-right addon-left">
                <option v-for="(option, index) in $attrs.options"
                    :key="index"
                    v-bind:value="option.value">
                    {{$t(option.text)}}
                </option>
            </select>
            <input
                    v-else
                    :value="value"
                    v-on="listeners"
                    v-bind="$attrs"
                    class="form-control"
                    :class="[{'is-valid': valid === true}, {'is-invalid': valid === false}, inputClasses]"
                    aria-describedby="addon-right addon-left">
        </slot>
// ...
</template>
```

However, it only renders following html:

```
<select aria-describedby="addon-right addon-left" type="select" class="form-control"></select>
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I used `options` for props. In vue.js `options` is a reserved keyword. I replaced it with `optionlist` and it works perfectly.